# getting "message": "Internal Server Error" error

Tags: python, google-chrome, localhost

While running the code in localhost I am getting `{"message": "Internal Server Error"}` error. I think it is because of using the browser function. How do I rectify the problem? I think it occurs in this line:

```
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
```

or is there any other way to get an all hyperlink from a google search result

```
from googlesearch import search
from mechanize import Browser
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
def thirdstep(question):
    br =Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_equiv(False) 
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; 
rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
e=0

    for url in search(question, tld='es', lang='es', stop=10):
        br.open(url)
        similarity_value=fuzz.token_set_ratio(question,br.title())
        if(similarity_value>e):
            e=similarity_value
            f=br.title()
            g=url

    return(g)
```

EG.how world war 2 ends?
=>www.primaryhomeworkhelp.co.uk › war › end

Comment: Hint: give your variables useful names. You will have to lookup the whole context to understand lines like `e=c`.

Comment: What libraries and imports are you using for this?

Comment: from googlesearch import search,
from mechanize import Browser,
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, are the libraries i am using